# gl.attachShader is not an object

Tags: javascript, webgl2

I have added webGL2 as the context for the canvas but have an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'attachShader' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': parameter 2 is not of type 'WebGLShader'.
at CreateProgram (index.html:88)
at index.html:107
```

I also:

- Tried using "webgl" instead of "webgl2" on the "canvas.getContext..."

I am following the tutorial here: https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html

Full code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nl10-ZEP8JujGXMwHHVGaDF6KdhvZcfg/view?usp=sharing

Problem found here:

```
function CreateProgram(gl,vertexShader,fragmentShader) {

var program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

var success = gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS);

if(success) {

return program;

}

//Else delete program
console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
gl.deleteProgram(program);
```

}

Comment: It's probably best to check for errors after compilng a shader `var success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS); if (!success) { console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your GLSL fragment has a syntax error, which causes the type error.

pay attention to the line 47

you should use `outColour = vec4(1,0,0.5,1);` instead of `outColour = vec4{1,0,0.5,1};`